# Laravel 5, assumindo variavel em consulta vazia?

Tags: laravel-5, if, querybuilder

Tenho uma consulta, porém algumas vezes essa consulta me retorna um valor vazio (*sem registros*).

Estes resultados da consulta, são direcionados para geração de um gráfico *HighCharts*, porém quando não existe valores dentro da consulta, o gráfico não é gerado.

Minha ideia seria montar um `if` sempre que a consulta retornasse vazio, porém não estou conseguindo.

```php
$vel_a2 = DB::table('ocorrencias')
      ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as qnt_cnt, velocidade'))
      ->where('cliente',$request->cliente)
      ->where('velocidade','=','A2')
      ->groupBy('velocidade')
      ->get();
if(empty($vel_a2))
{
   $vel_a2 = array('qnt_cnt'=> 0, 'velocidade'=>'A2');
}
```

Toda a vez que consulta fosse vazia, assumira um `array` para enviar para o gráfico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando é utilizado o [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) para resgatar informações de tabelas em seu banco de dados o resultado é sempre uma [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections) pertencente [Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html), resumindo é uma classe.

Se essa coleção vai conter registro ou não pouco importa porque o resultado é sempre a instância da classe [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections) e por isso a sua verificação é errado, primeiro deveria verificar se houve retorno e depois verificar se tem items em sua coleção, ***exemplo*** no seu código:

```
if(is_null($vel_a2) || $vel_a2->count() == 0)
{
    $vel_a2 = array('qnt_cnt'=> 0, 'velocidade'=>'A2');
}
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries)
- [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections)
- [Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ficou muito claro a explicação e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!